anyway to serve local large video file to html element in .net maui blazor hybrid app?
To reduce net traffic, these video files are only downloaded from server once and stored in cache dir. Every time playing video is fetched from local storage.
<video src="file:///path/to/video.mp4"> is not available for error message "Not allowed to load local resource". but local file is readable in C# segment. is there anyway to feed C# filestream object to html? js method URL.createObjectURL requires file instead of filestream. It's impossible to load whole video file instantly.
UPDATE:
I found DotNetStreamReference to do this, refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-8.0#stream-from-net-to-javascript But I meet a new Error Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendBuffer' on 'SourceBuffer': Overload resolution failed.
The whole code in Home.razor is:
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<p>@filepath</p>
<video src="" />

<script>
    async function streamToJavaScript(streamRef) {
        const video = document.querySelector("video");
        const stream = await streamRef.stream();
        const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
        video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
        mediaSource.addEventListener("sourceopen", () => {
            const sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"');
            sourceBuffer.addEventListener("updateend", () => {
                mediaSource.endOfStream();
                video.play();
                //console.log(mediaSource.readyState); // ended
            });
            sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(stream);
        });
    }
</script>

@code {
    string filepath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.CacheDirectory, "01_welcome.mp4");
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
        using var file = File.OpenRead(filepath);
        using var streamRef = new DotNetStreamReference(file, true);
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("streamToJavaScript", streamRef);
    }
}


Are you correctly converting the stream to a Uint8Array? Can you exclude a mismatched codec specification in SourceBuffer? Also, check if the stream chunks are not empty. Have you tried logging the type and size of data being passed to appendBuffer? Any information on how the data is processed before it reaches appendBuffer could be helpful to indentify the cause.
